# Fedora 23: Changing from Plasma to MATE

Tags: fedora, desktop-environment, mate-desktop, plasma

I am running Fedora 23 with Plasma desktop env.
I just installed MATE using the command: `dnf install mate-desktop` but in the login screen I can't see "MATE" as an option for desktop env. 
I only see there two options: "Plasma" and "Failsafe".

Why? and how can switch from plasma to MATE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `dnf groupinstall mate-compiz` (I got this by running `dnf grouplist -v`). That will install all of the packages that are part of the MATE desktop environment, rather than just the `mate-desktop` package, which (even tithe name suggests more) is just this:

```
Name        : mate-desktop
[...]
Summary     : Shared code for mate-panel, mate-session, mate-file-manager, etc
Description : The mate-desktop package contains an internal library
            : (libmatedesktop) used to implement some portions of the MATE
            : desktop, and also some data files and other shared components of
            : the MATE user environment.
```

You may also want `dnf groupinstall mate-applications`.